# Shapeless Witness and how it can give the actual singleton type

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless, type-level-computation

I'm trying to understand singleton types in shapeless and faced misunderstanding about singleton types compile-time type. Here is an example:

```
val x: Witness.`120`.T = 120.narrow
```

It works fine, but this constructions looks very unusual. What is `Witness.120`? In IDE it points to some macro function [`selectDynamic`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L62):

```
def selectDynamic(tpeSelector: String): Any = macro SingletonTypeMacros.witnessTypeImpl
```

which has compile-time type `Any` and judging by the construction `Witness.120.T` a `type` member `T`. This looks like magic... Can anyone give some explanation on what actually is going on when one writes something like:

```
val x: Witness.`120`.T = //...
```

Comment: The explanation is a bit more complex and I hope someone will write a more detailed answer later. But for now, let me give you a simplification. Scala's type system knew about singleton types since _(almost)_ is very first versions, for example the types of `objects`. However, for literals _(e.g. `120`)_ we didn't have a way to express and directly use such types in code until `2.13`. What the shapeless witness provides for previous versions of Scala is a way to access those. It works as a **macro** which generates a new instance of the class `Witness` whose **type parameter** `T` is singleton

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez _It works as a macro which generates a new instance of the class Witness whose type parameter T is singleton_ Are you sure it generates a subtype of `Witness`. I ran some experiments and from a compile error I saw it seemed it was `AnyRef{type T = Int(120); type ->>[V(in type ->>)] = V(in type ->>) with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Int(120),V(in type ->>)]; type Field[V(in type Field)] = V(in type Field) with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Int(120),V(in type Field)]}`. Pretty crazy type definition...

Comment: Yeah, the type is somewhat complex and to be honest, I am not really sure if it is a subtype of a witness or just an anonymous class. The point is, the macro is able to access the internals of the compiler, between those it could find the singleton type of `120` _(Here: `type T = Int(120)`)_ and to let you use it, it creates a new instance of a class which has a **type member** _(type parameter was a typo in my previous comment)_ which contains such type so you can access it. The select dynamic is another complex part, I would not really dive deep to understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

`Witness` creates a so-called *literal-based singleton type*. *Literal type* means it's a type that can only accept one value.

So if you create a function like this:

```
def f(x: Witness.`120`.T) = x
```

it would accept only integer `120`, but not `121`.

Since **Scala 2.13** [literal types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) are integrated into the language, so you can write it simply as:

```
def f(x: 120) = x
```

Function `narrow` narrows type of value `120` from general `Int` to literal `120`.